# Using backbone collections with a rest route that returns an object

Tags: rest, backbone.js

Looking at the example code

```
var accounts = new Backbone.Collection;
accounts.url = '/accounts';

accounts.fetch();
```

this works if the route returns an array

```
[{id:1, name:'bob'}, {id:2, name:'joe'}]
```

but the REST service I'm using returns an object like this

```
{
  items: [{id:1, name:'bob'}, {id:2, name:'joe'}],
  page: 1,
  href: '/acounts'
}
```

How to I go about telling `Backbone.Collection` that the collection is in `items`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse function seems appropriate.

From the documentation:
http://backbonejs.org/

"When fetching raw JSON data from an API, a Collection will automatically populate itself with data formatted as an array, while a Model will automatically populate itself with data formatted as an object:

[{"id": 1}] ..... populates a Collection with one model.
{"id": 1} ....... populates a Model with one attribute.
However, it's fairly common to encounter APIs that return data in a different format than what Backbone expects. For example, consider fetching a Collection from an API that returns the real data array wrapped in metadata:

```
{
  "page": 1,
  "limit": 10,
  "total": 2,
  "books": [
    {"id": 1, "title": "Pride and Prejudice"},
    {"id": 4, "title": "The Great Gatsby"}
  ]
}
```

In the above example data, a Collection should populate using the "books" array rather than the root object structure. This difference is easily reconciled using a parse method that returns (or transforms) the desired portion of API data:

```
var Books = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '/books',
  parse: function(data) {
    return data.books;
  }
});
```

"

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, yes, yes. Thank you for this.